# For $A$ and $B$ $\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ prove that $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$ share a common solution set iff we can get $B$ from $A$ through row operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know the converse of this statement is true, but is it biconditional?

Comment: What is the *solution set* of a matrix?

Comment: Yes (assuming they have the same sizes)

Comment: sorry, replace "matrices" with "linear systems" or "augmented matrices"

Answer (score 1):

If the solution spaces of $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$ are the same (that is, if $A$ and $B$ have *the same nullspace*, then we can indeed get from $A$ to $B$ using row operations.

To show that this is the case: note that for two matrices in reduced row echelon form to have the same nullspace, they must be equal.  Then, note that $A$ and $B$ can both be brought to row echelon form (or back from row echelon form) with row operations.